# I am using nutch rest api to the generate segements in nutch it is working nutch version(1.17)

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I have written nutch rest api that is generate type but it is not creating segments.
command is

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
  "crawlId":"crawl01",
  "type":"GENERATE",
  "confId":"default",
  "args":{"crawldb":"/root/nutch_source/runtime/local/testingapi/crawldb","segments_dir":"/root/nutch_source/runtime/local/testingapi/segments","numFetchers":"50"}
}' 'localhost:8081/job/create'
```

but ouput showing shoiwng finished the job but it is not creating the segment.May I know is there anything wrong in command.

Comment: Why you need to run the job via API ? Is CLI not enough for this purpose

Comment: @Shafiq I want to run via rest api aao that i can run remotely.

Comment: @Shafiq I think you are also exploring about the nutch.

Comment: I am working on Nutch (remotely) for about 4 years. You can use ssh to access your remote cluster. APIs are good only when you need to integrate its status into 3rd party application

Comment: @Shafiq can you share your profile to connect becuase I have some doubts can I ask personally.

Comment: Sure: you can access me via https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammad-shafiq-57a8a72b/